# How do I count in SQL Server occurences in put in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID      Offered  SalesID ItemID  DateTime
------------------------------------------
123456     1     36     1       2015-08-17  
123456     1     36     2       2015-08-17  
123456     1     36     3       2015-08-17
```

How do I count that the `Offered` column with value of 1 occurs 3 times in another column ?

Comment: In which other column? What output columns do you want?

Comment: i'm sorry,  i meant to put in a new column that shows the count on each row

Comment: So you want another column `OfferedCount` that would be "3" for all rows in your example?

Comment: yes. OfferedCount Column is fine, and yes 3 next to the each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table to a subquery that finds the frequency for the `Offered` value:

```
select s.*, OfferedCount
from (select Offered, count(*) OfferedCount
      from Sales group by Offered) c
join Sales s on s.Offered = c.Offered
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97e09/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (123456, 1, 36, 1, '2015-08-17'),  
        (123456, 1, 36, 2, '2015-08-17'),  
        (123456, 1, 36, 3, '2015-08-17')  
    ) AS x(ID, Offered, SalesID, ItemID, DateTime)
)
SELECT *, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Offered = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS OfferedCount
FROM cte
```

If your `Offered` column is just a bit column, you can simplify it by just summing it rather than the CASE expression that I've got.